# dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem

Tags: node.js

I am try to to install nodejs(sudo apt-get install nodejs) in Ubantu 18.04 with terminal, i got a error 
Please help me.

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: problem is solve thankyou for asking me sir